# Chrome Version 58.0.3000.4 dev (64-bit) CSS rendering issue

Tags: css

I noticed a strange problem on Latest Chrome Version 58.0.3000.4 dev (64-bit) My website is broken on Latest chrome DEV (Version 58.0.3000.4)[on MacOS] if you have latest chrome please check this URL http://openspeedtest.com/Get-widget.php
[image]
[image]

As you can see the buttons and animation Not rendering as expected. But working as expected on all other browser.

```
    .example {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, black);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}#ostui{
    background-color: white;
    height: 700px;
    width: 730px;
}
#min_speed, #max_speed {
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:208px;
    z-index:4;
    color:#35393c;
    font-weight:700
}
#min_speed {
    float:left;
    left:63px
}
#max_speed {
    right:63px;
    float:right
}
#speedometer {
    width:719px;
    height:268px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    background-color: #E5E6E7;
    display:none;
}
#speedometer #inside_central {
    top:18px;
    left:3px;
    position:relative;
    width:257px;
    height:257px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#speedometer #surface_plate {
    border-bottom-style: solid !important;
    border-bottom-width: 10px !important;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
    top:-257px;
    z-index:2;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}
#inside_central #direction_sign {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
    width:40px;
    height:43px;
    z-index:3;
    overflow:hidden
}

#one_ink_visible {
    position:absolute;
    width:257px;
    height:257px;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:7px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(74deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(74deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(74deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(74deg)
}
#speedometer #inside_left, #speedometer #inside_right {
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
    width:200px;
    height:222px;
    text-align:center
}
#speedometer #inside_left {
    left:25px;
    float:left
}
#speedometer #inside_right {
    left:0;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px
}
.side_ink {
    background:url('http://get.openspeedtest.com/images/side-blue-ink.png');
    position:absolute;
    top:-43px;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    height:222px;
    z-index:1
}
#inside_right .side_ink {
    display:none
}
#inside_left .side_ink {
    display:none
}
img#ink_segments {
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative
}
#direction_sign {
    display:none
}
#direction_sign img {
    left:0;
    top:-43px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3
}
.digital_speed {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:45px;
    font-weight:400;
    z-index:3;
    position:relative
}
#digital_speed_current {
    top:105px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute
}
#digital_speed_down, #digital_speed_up {
    top:45px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center
}
.speed_caption {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    z-index:3;
    position:relative
}
#speed_caption_current {
    top:159px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:700
}
#speed_caption_down, #speed_caption_up {
    position:absolute;
    top:99px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
    font-weight:700
}
/************************/
#speedometer_container{
    display:block;
}
#speedometer_controller{
    width: 719px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
}
#progress_bar {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:606px;
    height:73px;
    background:url('http://get.openspeedtest.com/images/horizontal-progress-bar.png') no-repeat top center;
    display:none;
    z-index:4
}
#progress_text, #ping_result {
    font-weight:700;
    left:170px;
    top:35px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:12px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-right:20px
}
#progress_bar_indicator {
    font-weight:700;
    top:16px;
    left:521px;
    background:#198bd9;
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute
}
#start_button_wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height:auto;
    left:8px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:4;
}
input.formatted_button {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(#28adf0),
        to(#117acf));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #28adf0, #117acf);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #4887c7;
    box-shadow:
        1px 1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    text-shadow:
        0px 1px 1px rgba(000,000,000,0.3),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    margin-bottom:10px;
    outline:none;

}

input.formatted_button:hover {
    border-top-color: #1090e6;

}

input.formatted_button:active {
    top:2px;
    position:relative;
    border-top-color: #1090e6;
    background: #117acf;
}
input.formatted_button_bw {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #303030;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(#f7f7f9),
        to(#e0e4e8));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f9, #e0e4e8);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-shadow:
        0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
input.formatted_button_bw:hover {
    border-top-color: #e0e4e8;
    background: #e0e4e8;
}

input.formatted_button_bw:active {
    top:2px;
    position:relative;
    border-top-color: #e0e4e8;
    background: #e0e4e8;
}
#ip_container {
    font-family: 'PT Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#ip_address {
    font-weight: 300;
}
#chart_container{
    width:490px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:-17px;
    top:17px;
    left:-10px;
    position:relative;
}

.spinner {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: #44A8FC;

  border-radius: 100%;  
  -webkit-animation: scaleout .5s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: scaleout .5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.0) }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleout {
  0% { 
    transform: scale(0.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
  } 100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug on Latest chrome Dev. I reported the same https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=689369